# Change tooltip color depending on class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a page that uses tooltips.  Previously there were only "warning" tooltips that were mainly red, with lighter red warning messages, but now I want some "info" tooltips in a less threatening shade.  I've created a css class called info-tooltip

```
.text-info {
    color: #17a2b8 !important; /* This is the color of the tooltip itself */
}

.info-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #a6ecf7 !important; /* This is the desired color for the tooltip message box */
}

.info-tooltip + .tooltip .arrow:before {
    border-top-color: #a6ecf7 !important; /* This is the desired color for the tooltip message box */
}
```

and in my markup I have the following:

```
<span style="font-size: 1.5em" class="text-info glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign info-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="example text"></span>
```

In my javascript I have:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

However, while the tooltip itself has the correct color, when you hover over it the message "example text" is shown in the default color, and not my chosen color.  I don't want to override the default color because it's the correct color for the warning message and messages on other pages.

[image]

Comment: use !important - is it not for gentlemen?:)

Comment: if you cared to look at the sample code you'd see that I have used !Important